# Magento Customer Grid Row Not Working within Dialog Model based Popup

Tags: magento

var url = "getUrl('/adminhtml/getGrid'); ?>?";

Dialog.info({url: url, options: {method: 'get'}}, 
        {className: "magento", top:40, width:650,zIndex:100,resizable:true,title:'New Answer',closable:true});

I am using the above code to create Dialog Modal based Popup Grid. Grid is loaded using ajax request in magento.Customer grid will be displayed within Popup but grid row action not working. I Expecting perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

We need key for admin urls. You can get Adminhtml urls using following :

$url =  Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("yourmodule/adminhtml_yourcontroller/youraction");

Comment: URL has been passed in title.But, Still Grid row Action not Working. Please help

Comment: In grid row action, are you referring to grid filters or select options?

Comment: I specified edit action, when normally row can be clicked , that row will be allowed to edit action. That action can  not working.